# Jquery deferred for search in while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, jquery-deferred, deferred

I need to search making multiple async queries - portion is 500 results a time (in sharepoint client object model) and finally give user back all the results.

I'm new in javascript, so I ask your advice how I can make it work. 
I've made a simple example for demo of what I need

```
var results;
var promises = [];

function Search(startRow) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() { 
        alert(startRow); 
        //results+= ... - search results for the current startRow
        d.resolve(); }, 
        3000);

    return d.promise();
}

var portion = 500;
var startRow = 0;
var rowCount = 2002;
while (rowCount > startRow + portion) {                                
    startRow += portion;
    promises.push(Search(startRow));
}

$.when.apply($, promises).then(
    function(){ 
        alert('done'); // get all search results here 
    });
```

So what I need is to get the right current startRow in the Search function

UPD: All the alerts are called with the last startRow

Comment: "*So what I need is to get the right current startRow in the Search function*". You already got it, haven't you?

Comment: No, all the alerts are called with the last startRow

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what exactly you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it like this. Are there any better ways?

```
        var results;
    var promises = [];

    function Search() {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        setTimeout(function() { 
            alert(startRows[0]); 
            startRows.splice(0, 1);
            //results+= ... 
            d.resolve(); }, 
            3000);

        return d.promise();
    }

    var startRows = [];
    var portion = 500;
    var startRow = 0;
    var rowCount = 2002;
    while (rowCount > startRow + portion) {                                
        startRow += portion;
        startRows.push(startRow);
        promises.push(Search());
    }

    $.when.apply($, promises).then(
        function(){ 
            alert('done'); // get all search results here 
        });
```